# npm install dependencies fails in vagrant ubuntu with shared folder

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

host OS: Ubuntu 14.04.

When doing npm install I get the following errors.

```
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-pngquant@4.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-optipng@4.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-jpegtran@4.0.0
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing imagemin-gifsicle@4.0.0
npm ERR! EEXIST, open '/home/vagrant/.npm/bc688003--npm-gulp-util-3-0-2-package-tgz.lock'
File exists: /home/vagrant/.npm/bc688003--npm-gulp-util-3-0-2-package-tgz.lock
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-34-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--no-bin-link"
npm ERR! cwd /home/vagrant/tixif/telmo-web
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/.npm/bc688003--npm-gulp-util-3-0-2-package-tgz.lock
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I have tried: npm install --no-bin-links, also I tried adding the below to my vagrant file.

```
 vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "VBoxInternal2/SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate/vagrant", "1"]
```

Still not working. Thank you for your responses in advance.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you may have run `--no-bin-link` instead of `--no-bin-links`. Give it another go?

Comment: Make sure you run vagrant up as administrator, and also npm install as root.